# How to set MDB_NOTLS mode in python lmdb

Tags: python, database, lmdb

In lmdb docs: 
"MDB_NOTLS mode is used exclusively, which allows read transactions to freely migrate across threads and for a single thread to maintain multiple read transactions. This enables mostly care-free use of read transactions, for example when using gevent."

But there is no manual how to set it in python.

I tried:

```
import os
os.environ['MDB_NOTLS'] = '1'
import lmdb
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Found that in python it is switched on by default.